# Create a certificate for app which is used APNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a question on creating a certificate for submitting an app to the app store. In my app, i am using APNS. When creating a certificate, do i need to select  only App Store and Ad Hoc or both App Store and Ad Hoc and Apple Push Notification service SSL(Production) under production section. Anyway when i am creating provisioning profile i am enabling push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

For app store you can select only Apple Push Notification service SSL (Production).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You select only app Store. Add hoc distribution should use only for development phase.

Comment: Please see above screenshot of @Jugal Kishore.From that which one i need to select.